# How do I wipe a harddrive with Ubuntu on it?

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, uninstall, reset

I want to completely wipe a harddrive with Ubuntu on it, so I can put Windows back on it. How do I do that? I don't want to dual boot either, I just want to wipe the drive and put Windows on it. How do I do this? Thanks!

-Trace

Comment: Just put the windows cd in your computer boot from it and follow the steps. Although I would think about it before removing  a Linux installation since there is a lot to learn from it.

Comment: @Falk I don't have the CD. Say I just had Ubuntu on an SSD and wanted to reinstall Windows via USB. But, before installation, I wanted to wipe the hardrive to make sure Ubuntu was not still on it. How do I do THAT?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly from Windows installer, just select "Advanced" partitioning, remove all partitions of your drive, create a new one (Windows will create addtitional partitions - recovery and ESP) and proceed as in normal installation.

Alternatively you could use Live CD/Live USB of some Linux distribution, e.g. drive you installed Ubuntu from. Click "Try Ubuntu without installing". There are variety of tools you can use at this point. For GUI operation I'd recommend [GParted](http://gparted.org), you can install it using `apt-get install gparted` like you'd do on regular Ubuntu installation. Operation is preety straightforward, but in case of problems you can refer to [manual](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual).

**Please note that this will remove all your data from the drive you kept Ubuntu on!**